# Power BI. Remove duplicates but keep null values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

In Power BI, I need to remove duplicates of a column but keep the null values as they are 'pending'. Is there a way I can do it with DAX or the Query Editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filter the table in two ways, without nulls and only nulls.

On the table without nulls, remove duplicates. `Home > Remove Rows > Remove Duplicates`

Append the null rows to this table.

The M code will look like this:

```
let
    Source = <Data source or previous step reference here>,
    AllNulls = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column1] = null)),
    NoNulls = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column1] <> null)),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(NoNulls),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Duplicates", AllNulls})
in
    #"Appended Query"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the query editor.

1. Add an index column (Add Column tab > Index Column)
2. Add a Custom Column with this formula ([Test] is your original column with nulls and duplicates.

[image]

3. Right-click the latest column [Temp] and select `Remove Duplicates`
4. Remove [Index] and [Temp] columns

Comment: The one thing you need to be careful about with this if your `[Test]` column has a null in row N and the column also contains the value N in another row, then one of those rows gets removed when deleting duplicates.

Comment: @Alexis Olson. You're right off course. I made my solution more robust, by adding some random characters to the index value. See edit.